# _forEach implementation in JS returning undefined

Tags: javascript, foreach, functional-programming

Edit: This is actually, as pointed out by other users, an implementation of _map, since _forEach is not meant to return a copy of the array.

I'm trying to understand how functions like _forEach work. For that, I came up with a _forEach implementation.
However, my implementation is currently just returning an array of undefined elements, but I really don't see where it's going wrong.

```js
function _forEach(arr, cb) {
  var storage = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    storage.push(cb(arr[i], i, arr));
  }
  return storage;
}
var list = ["hay", "lal", "pay"];
list = _forEach(list, function(name, i, list) {
  name.replace("a", "");
});

console.log(list);
```

To my understanding, `storage.push(cb(arr[i], i, arr))` should store the returned value from the callback into the new array, and then `return storage` should have a copy of the altered array.

But the result of console.log(list) after the invocation is just [undefined, undefined, undefined].
However, if I add a `console.log(name.replace('a', ''))` in the callback, I can see that the filter is being applied correctly. So why is it not storing the altered element into the new array?

Comment: Try inserting some console logs in your _forEach function and your invocation of it, to trace whats happening behind the scenes.

Comment: your callback function doesn't return anything, hence undefined.  also _forEach should be _map really

Comment: @GetSet I have added console.log in the callback, I can see that it's filtering the words correctly, it' just not storing them.

Comment: @user120242 yes I know realize that this would actually be _map since _forEach shouldn't return a copy. In any case, how come the callback is not returning anything? MDN says that str.filter returns the filtered string.

Comment: no, your function doesn't have a return statement.  it's just name.replace('a','') without returning the value.  `(function(name, i, list){ name.replace('a','') })('name',10, [])` returns `undefined`

Comment: I tested @user120242 advice with your code. Your code works but is just missing the return. Im sure you can find it.

Comment: I was unaware that the return only "goes up 1 level", so while the .replace function was returning something, this value was staying inside the scope of the callback and thus the callback itself was not returning any value. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I want to note that @RaghulSk 's edit is highly debatable opinion on style, and should not influence your decision on how you write your code.  I don't know why anyone would approve that edit as if it actually improved readability in any way.

Comment: @Elmambo2194 think of it like `const valueToPush = cb(arr[i], i, arr); storage.push(valeToPush)`. Just like with any function, for `cb` to return a value to assign to `valueToPush`, it needs a return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes also the glossary is important,
you are using (implementing) a forEach and expecting it to behave as a map.

[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is meant to just run a callback on every item in the list, no other purposes...

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is indeeed what we expect to *map* items from `A` to `B` and accumulate them into a new array (`Functor f => (a → b) → f a → f b`).

```js
const original = ["hay", "lal", "pay"];

const withoutA = original.map(
  (word) => word.replace(/a/gi, ''),
);

console.log(
  'original without "a"',
  withoutA
);
```

- [forEach VS map](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f)

Answer (score 1):

1. You are doing something like `map` not `forEach`. Check out `Array.prototype.map` for more information.
2. Your callback does not have return value, therefore it will be always `undefined`.

```js
list = _forEach(list, function(name, i, list) {
  name.replace("a", "");
});
```

convert it to

```js
list = _forEach(list, function(name, i, list) {
  return name.replace("a", "");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the return value of the callback function as below.

```js
function _forEach(arr, cb) {
 
  var storage = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    storage.push(cb(arr[i], i, arr));
  }
  return storage;
}
var list = ["hay", "lal", "pay"];
list = _forEach(list, function(name, i, list) {
  return name.replace("a", "");
});

console.log(list);
```